# Determine time since process start on Linux

Tags: linux, time

Within a process is there an API I can use to programatically determine the wall-clock time since the process started, on Linux?

Comment: duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780824

Comment: man time: https://linux.die.net/man/1/time

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco - sorry, but it wasn't clear, but I'm looking for an API to use _within_ a running process to determine the time it has been running.

Comment: @user1462442 - if it's a duplicate, it isn't obvious (to me anyways). Where can the answer be found there? I see mostly mentions of a few Linux utilities that report things like CPU time.

Comment: @BeeOnRope found this answer, hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553466/3589567

Comment: @BeeOnRope you can subprocess call the bash utilities or read /proc file system. OS is an application library itself.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: @jww I guess C or C++. I guess some languages might offer this as part of their runtime, e.g., take a timestamp early in the startup process and then offer the option to query this (like [this in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/817835/149138)), but it misses whatever happens before the timestamp is taken - unless of course they don't use the "early timestamp" approach but instead ask the OS, in which case I'd be interested to know.