# Deleting files based on CreationTime

Tags: linux, bash, unix, unix-timestamp

In a directory there are files which are generated daily. 
Format of files, if its generated on 16th Apr 2012 is TEST_20120416.

So I need to delete all the files which are older than 7 days. I tried doing this

```
#!/bin/ksh
find /data/Test/*.* -mtime -7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
exit 0
```

Now the problem is above code is deleting based on modification time but according to requirement file should delete based on creation time.Kindly help me out in deleting files based on filename(filename has timestamp).

Comment: [File creation time depends on file-system][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929419/how-to-get-file-creation-date-in-linux

Comment: @tuxuday ... and in fact the majority of file systems out there do not even keep track of file creation time. Many have naively interpreted `ctime` as "creation time", but that is not what it is at all...

Answer (score 0):

As you fortunately have creation date encoded in filename, this should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
REFDATE=$(date --date='-7 days' +%Y%m%d)
PREFIX=TEST_
find /data/Test/ -name $PREFIX\* | while read FNAME; do
   if [ ${FNAME#$PREFIX} -lt $REFDATE ]; then
       rm $FNAME
   fi
done
```

It will print warnings if you have some other files with names starting with TEST_ in which case some more filtering may be needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
find /data/Test/*.* -ctime -7 -delete
```

'find /data/Test/*.*' will find the all the files in the /data/Test folder and argument '-ctime -7' will limit the search to the creation time to last 7 days and -delete option will delete such files

Comment: `-mtime` filters on modification time. A propably better choice would be `-ctime`. Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10171069/694576

Comment: If you post a one-liner as an answer, at least explain in one or two sentences what it is doing. Noone will execute random commands from Internet on their machine.

Comment: Ok, my bad. find /data/Test/*.* will find the all the files in the /data/Test folder and argument -ctime -7 will limit the search to the creation time to last 7 days and -delete option will delete such files

Comment: @Debu - you might want to simply edit your answer instead of commenting on it.