# How to find file creation date in Windows using Go

Tags: windows, go

I was hoping to find the created date of a file in Windows. How would I be able to accomplish this simply?

I have been using `os.Stat` and `os.Chtimes` to get other file information but it does not seem to offer information on created date.

Comment: The Go standard library does not have file creation dates readily available, because it is heavily oriented around how the Linux kernel works, which does not have information about the creation time of files. However, for other platforms, the following library looks like a worthy contender: https://github.com/djherbis/times

Comment: @Zyl: The package you link to gets the windows filesystem times using the std library, so you can't really say that the std library doesn't have the times available.

Comment: @Zyl: It's also unfair to say it's "heavily oriented around Linux". More accurate: It's heavily oriented around features broadly available across all OSes. OS-specific features (whether for Linux or Windows or others) are hidden, and require extra work.

Comment: Note that some Unix/Linux file systems *do* have the concept of file-creation time (BSD calls this "birthtime" and ext4 and ZFS both store one). See also [File creation time in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10171069/1256452).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`FileInfo.Sys`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#FileInfo) method returns the system specific data structures. On Windows, this will be a `syscall.Win32FileAttributeData`, which looks like

```
type Win32FileAttributeData struct {
    FileAttributes uint32
    CreationTime   Filetime
    LastAccessTime Filetime
    LastWriteTime  Filetime
    FileSizeHigh   uint32
    FileSizeLow    uint32
}
```

Getting the creation time would look something like:

```
d := fi.Sys().(*syscall.Win32FileAttributeData)
cTime = time.Unix(0, d.CreationTime.Nanoseconds())
```

Since this is windows specific, this of course should be protected by build constraints. Either using a `_windows.go` file or `//go:build windows`

Comment: Note that `fi` is the `fs.FileInfo` retuned by `os.Stat`.

Comment: @ShaneBishop, yes the type has been moved to the `fs` package, which is why there is a type alias in the `os` package, but they are still functionally the same type. I updated the link directly to the `fs` package type.