# "The handle is invalid" error when calling GetFileInformationByHandle with handle initialized with GetFileVersionInfoSize

Tags: windows, go

I am trying to programmatically obtain file information with Go on Windows, including the time the file was created.

I found a function in [`golang.org/x/sys/windows`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows) that returns something with information on when a file is created is `GetFileInformationByHandle` ([Go docs](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#GetFileInformationByHandle), [Windows API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle)). However, the code I wrote using this function gives me a `The handle is invalid` error.

Here is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    name := `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

    fileInfo, err := os.Stat(name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to stat %s: %s", name, err.Error())
    }

    log.Printf("%s has base name %s.\n", name, fileInfo.Name())

    var handle windows.Handle
    _, err = windows.GetFileVersionInfoSize(name, &handle)
    if err != nil && err != windows.ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND && err != windows.ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND {
        log.Fatalf("GetFileVersionInfoSize error: path: %s %s", name, err.Error())
    }

    var hndlFileInfo windows.ByHandleFileInformation
    err = windows.GetFileInformationByHandle(handle, &hndlFileInfo)
    if err != nil {
        if err == windows.ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE { // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-
            log.Println("Error is invalid handle error.")
        }
        log.Fatalf("GetFileInformationByHandle error: path: %s %s", name, err.Error())
    }

    log.Println("Success!")
}
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
2023/01/11 14:43:19 C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe has base name cmd.exe.
2023/01/11 14:43:19 Error is invalid handle error.
2023/01/11 14:43:19 GetFileInformationByHandle error: path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe The handle is invalid.
```

I have confirmed that the file path is valid (plus the `os.Stat` call does not return an error):

[image]

I know the System32 directory is not visible for 32-bit Windows programs, but I have verified that my executable is a 64-bit program with the `file` tool on git-bash:

```
$ file win_handle_test.exe
win_handle_test.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
```

Since the path should be valid, what could I be doing wrong so that I am getting an invalid handle?

Comment: The 2nd argument of `GetFileVersionInfoSize` is documented in MSDN as «A pointer to a variable that the function sets to zero.» ;-) I think you should use `GetFileVersionInfo` followed by `VerQueryValue`. Consult MSDN docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate way to get the creation time, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59414161/8593689):

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    name := `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

    fileInfo, err := os.Stat(name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to stat %s: %s", name, err.Error())
    }

    log.Printf("%s has base name %s.\n", name, fileInfo.Name())

    data := fileInfo.Sys().(*syscall.Win32FileAttributeData)
    cTime := time.Unix(0, data.CreationTime.Nanoseconds())

    log.Printf("cTime in UTC           : %v\n", cTime.UTC())
    log.Printf("cTime in local timezone: %v\n", cTime)
}
```

Output:

```
2023/01/11 15:03:58 C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe has base name cmd.exe.
2023/01/11 15:03:58 cTime in UTC           : 2022-05-10 17:34:57.9429156 +0000 UTC
2023/01/11 15:03:58 cTime in local timezone: 2022-05-10 13:34:57.9429156 -0400 EDT
```

This output matches the created time in the properties view for the file.

Despite the [`FILETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) itself being in time since January 1, 1601 UTC, both [`time.Unix`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Unix) and the [`Nanoseconds` function](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#Filetime.Nanoseconds) are based on time since January 1, 1970 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Go has native support for what you're after right in its stock `syscall` package:

```golang
//go:build windows

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(0)

    fi, err := os.Stat(`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fad, ok := fi.Sys().(*syscall.Win32FileAttributeData)
    if !ok {
        log.Println("No win32-native data")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(
            "FileAttributes:", fad.FileAttributes,
            "CreationTime:", fad.CreationTime,
            "LastAccessTime:", fad.LastAccessTime,
            "LastWriteTime:", fad.LastWriteTime,
            "FileSizeHigh:", fad.FileSizeHigh,
            "FileSizeLow:", fad.FileSizeLow,
        )
    }
}
```

On my system, I have:
`filever$ GOOS=windows go build`
`filever$ wine ./filever.exe`
`FileAttributes: 32 CreationTime: {868251897 31002635} LastAccessTime: {1168986901 31008247} LastWriteTime: {868251897 31002635} FileSizeHigh: 0 FileSizeLow: 795516`