# using linux system cmds from C

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have a c program that must get information about particular files on a linux machine.  For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
     system("/bin/stat /home/kehelc/programs/test.dtl | egrep Birth | awk '{ print $2, $3 }'");
     return 0;
}
```

This outputs:
2013-07-01 11:57:52.208220100

I want to now format this output so that it looks like:
Mon, 1 Jul, 2013 at 11:57:52

Can I do this with sed & awk?

thanks

Comment: Is there any reason to use `system()` rather than the `stat()` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file creation date in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929419/how-to-get-file-creation-date-in-linux)

Comment: C is not meant for scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use popen and read the output stream, then you can format it as you please ;)

```
   /* simply invoke a app, pipe output*/
    pipe = popen("ls -l", "r" );
    if (pipe == NULL ) {
        printf("invoking %s failed: %s\n", buf, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    waitfor(10);

    while(!feof(pipe) ) {
        if( fgets( buf, 128, pipe ) != NULL ) {
            printf("%s\n", buf );
        }
    }

    /* Close pipe */
    rc = pclose(pipe);
```

or you can use strftime directly in awk:

```
awk '{print strftime("%c", ( <timestamp in milliseconds> + 500 ) / 1000 )}'
```

see the strftime man page for reference 
http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

Comment: Isn't it more efficient to use `stat(2)` rather than `stat(1)`?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I agree, but that's not what he asked for :)

Comment: True, however suggesting a better approach altogether is OK.