# Find file by creation date in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

While I was searching for a solution to my problem , I saw that "Linux and UNIX like operating systems do not store file creation time." Is that true?

I want to know on which date a file is created (**NOT MODIFIED**). I do know that some commands like **find** command which shows me the last modified date but that is not what I am looking for. Is there any way to find the file creation date through shell script or commands?

Comment: `stat <file>` gives the `Birth` date. It has been answered in [su]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time

Comment: you can find answer also here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929419/how-to-get-file-creation-date-in-linux

Comment: @fedorqui, not at all filesystems: reiserfs has no such field.

Comment: In most Linux OS, you can **not** retrieve creation date, only last modification date (mtime)

Comment: @ fedorqui IF u read the link which you commented. It says that there is no such command that  does it. Basically it says unix doesn't store creation time. In that case stat will not work .

Comment: @Stunner yes, in some cases you can get the `Birth`, while in much of them not.

Comment: The topic of the time of file birth is also a philosophical question.  What happens if a file is moved?  What when it is copied?  Which of these retains the old birth date?