# How to get true file creation date in R, on Unix systems?

Tags: r, filesystems, system-calls, fileinfo

I'm trying to get file creation dates from R and I understand that this information might not be possible to retrieve at all on some operating systems that just don't store it anywhere. However, I'm unsure how to retrieve it generically when it *is* (at least, theoretically) retrievable.

On Windows, this is straight forward because `ctime` from `file.info` provides this information, for reference, this is the relevant excerpt from `?file.info`

> What is meant by the three file times depends on the OS and file system. On Windows native file systems ctime is the file creation time (something which is not recorded on most Unix-alike file systems).

However, although most unix systems don't record this information (as pointed out in the help), some unix-based systems such as OS X do in fact store this. On OS X, for example, the system command metadata ls `mdls` will print file metadata and list `kMDItemContentCreationDate` (the actual creation date of the file) as one of the file attributes.

My question is, what advice do people have for getting at file creation dates (if they are available at all) from file metadata? (e.g. specifically in the case of OS X where there's a system command but no direct R call)

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to info from the comments + details on SO and SE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929419/how-to-get-file-creation-date-in-linux) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4), I've come up with a way to solve this in R on OS X type unix platforms that track creation date and have the [BSD style `stat` command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html). However, I still couldn't figure out how to do this in R on other linux systems that track creation date but don't have this version of `stat`. In this answer on [unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4), it is suggested that this info could be retrieved with `debugfs + stat` even when `stat` itself does not report it (provided the file system records birthdate), but that solution I couldn't get to work (only linux I could test on didn't have `debugfs`). Anyways, here's how far I got:

```
get_birthdate <- function(filepath) {
  switch(Sys.info()[['sysname']],
         Windows = {
           # Windows
           file.info(filepath)$ctime
         },
         Darwin = {
           # OS X
           cmd <- paste('stat -f "%DB"', filepath) # use BSD stat command
           ctime_sec <- as.integer(system(cmd, intern=T)) # retrieve birth date in seconds from start of epoch (%DB)
           as.POSIXct(ctime_sec, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "") # convert to POSIXct
         },
         Linux  = {
           # Linux
           stop("not sure how to do this")
         })
}
```

Comment: On unix systems, ctime is (probably) the time of the directory entry creation, but that might not be the same time that the file was created.  This is because files on unix filesystems may have multiple directory entries pointing to them; Windows doesn't allow this, so the one-and-only ctime will be the actual file creation time.

Comment: Ok I see you can't just use `file.info('yourfilename')['ctime']` on Unix.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately ```ctime``` from ```file.info``` on unix is only the time of "last status change" which, if I understand it correctly, basically records the last time of change of any file content as well as non-data changes in things like file ownership, etc., that is to say, it's more like ```mtime``` and doesn't hold any information regarding creation time (directory entry or otherwise)

Comment: `file.info` uses `stat`, and for most Linux filesystems, you're not going to get creation time. `stat` returns last [access|mod|status change]. Ext4 (linux) stores the creation time (`crtime`) but you aren't going to be able to get it from R. NTFS also stores true creation time, but I'm also not sure how to get it from R. This SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4 thread might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following other's pointers, this *should* work quite reasonably.
Unfortunately it needs root privileges (dued to `debugfs`) and it's not very efficient yet (especially a bit quick'n dirty on regular expressions, but it's 01:00 o clock in the morning here :) ).

BTW, we set up the pager to be `cat` (making `debugfs` to print on standard output), find in which device the file is stored in order to use `debugfs` properly and finally get the stats and elaborate it a bit.

In general, in `UNIX`, once you have a bash-command to read its output in `R` you have to use `pipe` in read mode(that is default) and `readLines`.

Test done in a Debian Gnu Linux.

```
np350v5c:/home/l# R
> my.file <- "/etc/network/interfaces"
> 
> setup_pager <- function() {system("export PAGER=cat")}
> 
> where_is <- function(file) {
      con <- pipe(sprintf("df %s", file))
      res <- strsplit(readLines(con)[2], " ")[[1]][1]
      close(con)
      res
  }
> 
> where_is(my.file) # could be /dev/sda1 as well, depending on /etc/fstab
[1] "/dev/disk/by-uuid/9ce40c2b-60d8-40b1-890f-1e5da4199c88"
> 
> my.command <- sprintf("debugfs -R 'stat %s' %s",
                        my.file,
                        where_is(my.file))
> 
> ## root privileges especially here ..                                           
> setup_pager()
> con <- pipe(my.command)
> debugfs <- readLines(con)
debugfs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
> close(con)
> 
> my.date <- gsub("^crtime:.+-- ", "", grep("^crtime", debugfs, value = TRUE))
> my.date
[1] "Tue Feb 19 00:07:21 2013"
> strptime(tolower(substr(my.date, 5, nchar(my.date))),
           format = "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
[1] "2013-02-19 00:07:21 CET"
```

HTH, Luca

Comment: very nice, thank you very much for working through this!! one quick comment, I think even on unix systems, you can avoid the ```pipe``` and ```readLines``` combination by using ```system(., intern=T)```, so for example your ```where_is``` function can work like this as well: ```where_is <- function(file) strsplit(system(sprintf("df %s", file), intern = T)[2], " ")[[1]][1]``` (at least on the Red Hat server I could test this - unfortunately don't have root access to implement it fully though)

Comment: @sebkopf yes (tested), didn't know about intern parameter. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I know I am a little late to the game here, but here is a pretty easy solution for unix/Mac OS:

```
file.name <- "~/dir/file.extension"
df$file_created_dt <- system(paste0("stat -f %SB ", file.name), intern = T)
```

And then you can format it however you like:

```
df$file_created_dt <- as.POSIXct(df$file_created_dt, format = "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "your/timezone")
```