# c scanning folder for new files

Tags: c, directory, scanning

Hey i have to write a program which is scanning folder (unless we type 'q'), and when new file is found, prints it on. I've already wrote this for my last exercise and it works fine (simply scanning and printing ALL files in folder) but don't know how to deal with this problem.

```
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *ep;     
dp = opendir (directory);
if (dp != NULL)
{
  while (ep = readdir (dp))
{
puts (ep->d_name);
}
(void) closedir (dp);
}
else
perror ("Couldn't open the directory"); return 1;
```

edit:

Ok so i have already this:

```
pthread_mutex_t mojmuteks=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *change(char *status)
{
   int x=1;
   while(x==1)
   {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mojmuteks);
      *status=getchar();
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mojmuteks);
   }
}


main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *ep; 
struct stat file_stat;
time_t last=0;
char status='n';
pthread_t mojwatek;

if (pthread_create( &mojwatek, NULL, change, &status) )
{
    printf("błąd przy tworzeniu wątku.");
    abort(); 
}
pthread_mutex_lock(&mojmuteks); 
while(status!='q')
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mojmuteks);
    dp = opendir (argv[1]);
    last=file_stat.st_ctime;
     if (dp != NULL)
     {
        while (ep = readdir (dp))
        {
            stat(ep->d_name, &file_stat);
            if(last>file_stat.st_ctime)
            last=file_stat.st_ctime;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        perror ("Couldn't open the directory"); 
        return 1;
    }   
    (void) closedir (dp);  
    dp = opendir (argv[1]);
    if (dp != NULL)
      {
        while (ep = readdir (dp))
        {
                stat(ep->d_name, &file_stat);
                if(last<file_stat.st_ctime)
                puts (ep->d_name);
        }

      }
      else
      {
        perror ("Couldn't open the directory"); 
        return 1;
      }
      closedir(dp);  
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mojmuteks); 
}


return 0;
}
```

and have 2 more questions: using mutex, the "main" process after each route is waiting for respond from "change" instead of just running as long as we didnt'd type 'q', how to fix it? second question: i'm checking which file is older using st_ctime, but some files have always 0 value in this variable, why and how to fix it?

Comment: You have to get the confirmation from the user to print the file name???

Comment: _deal with this problem_ you don't really explain what the problem is either?

Comment: No, i dont need any comfirmations, user's is only able to press 'q' if he wants to finnish scanning

Answer (score 0):

You could note the time of the last scan and use the [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fstat) function on each file you scan which fills the [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) buffer you pass it with informations about the file of which you have passed the handle to. Just compare  the time of last scan with the creation time which you can get as decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929549/1113392). If the time of creation is youger than that of the last scan then you can print the filename.

Note that you may use [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat) isnstead of `fstat` if dont have a file handle and dont want to open the file only for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Normally to monitor changes on the filesystem you should use inotify (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). The API is a bit complex, so I guess it won't be a good fit for your purpose.

Please also note that your directory scanning routine doesn't descend into subdirectories (or deal with various links, pipes etc). For any purpose other than simply printing the name, you should use ftw (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)