# Get filesystem creation date in C

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, partition, ext4

I need to know the creation datetime of the filesystem on a disk (in a Linux machine) with C. I would like to avoid using shell commands, such as

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdb2 | grep 'Filesystem created:'
```

and make a parser.

Thanks

Comment: I'm searching for FileSystem creation datetime. The creation datetime of a file is easily editable.

Comment: tune2fs supports ext2/ext3/ext4, so you want to know ext filesystem creation datetime ?

Comment: Yes. My HardDisk is an ext4.

Comment: On most Unix filesystems  you can't; there is only {ctime,mtime,atime} And ctime is not time_of_creation, but time_of_change of inode attributes (such as rwx)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to know the layout of the superblock so that you can extract the `s_mkfs_time` member? Do you need some sample GPL source code? Some sample non-GPL source code? The part of tune2fs that does what you want is https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/master/lib/e2p/ls.c#L314

Comment: This GitHub link is what I needed! Thank you! I can't add you reputation. Make an answer, and I will charge you reputation!

Comment: Could you motivate your question and explain why you need the creation date of the file system? On some filesystems, that information does not exist! What would you do in such case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file creation date in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929419/how-to-get-file-creation-date-in-linux)

Comment: Without motivations, your question is unclear, and has no sense on some file systems. What is your program trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a program coded in C (or in any language capable of calling C routines) you would use the [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) system call (or, with *recent* kernels and *some* file systems, the [statx(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) one) to query the creation time of a given file (or directory). Of course, commands like [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) or [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) are using internally that [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) system calll.

There is no standard, and file system neutral, way to get the creation time of a given [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). That information is not always kept. I guess that [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) filesystems, or [distributed file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system#Distributed_file_systems) such as [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), don't keep that.

You might use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on the mount point of that file system.

The [statfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) system call retrieves some filesystem information, but does not give any time stamps.

For ext4 file systems, see [ext4(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) and use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html). You might parse `/proc/mounts`  and some `/proc/fs/ext4/*/` directory. The pseudofiles in `/proc/` can be [parsed quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108) and usually won't involve physical disk IO.

You could also work at the ext2/3/4 [disk partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) level, on an *unmounted* file `ext[234]` system, with a library like (or programs from) [e2fsprogs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git). You should not access (even just read) a disk partition containing some file system if that file system is mounted.

<sup>(your question should give some motivation and context)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check your samples.